# checking for string element in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's wrong with this?

```
var colours = ['red','green', 'blue']
console.log('blue' in colours);  // outputs false
```

It outputs false, I would have thought it should be trye.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the `in` operator in JavaScript is not as nice as it is e.g. in Python.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're dealing with an `Array` there you can't check for it that way. `Arrays` offer you the `Array.prototype.indexOf` method to determine whether or not something is in there:

```
console.log( colours.indexOf( 'blue' ) > -1 );
```

Explanation:

Arrays in ECMAscript are just specialized `Objects`. That means your Array really looks like

```
colours = {
    0: 'red',
    1: 'green',
    2: 'blue'
};
```

Since the `in` operator only checks for object `keys`, you cannot check for values with it. You indeed could check for `if('1' in colours)` for instance (which would return `true`), but that doesn't make much sense. Again, use `.indexOf()` for Arrays.

Side-note: ECMAscript Harmony (ES.Next, or ES6) will give is the `for of` loop which instead of keys, enumerates object values. I'm not quite sure if we can use the `of` operator the same way as `in`, but it would be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `colours.indexOf('blue')`.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work on objects. It checks whether an object has a property.

```
var colours = { red: 123, green: true, blue: "foo"};;
console.log("blue" in colours);
```

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in modern browsers:

```
var colours = ['red','green', 'blue'];
console.log(colours.indexOf("blue") != -1);
```